# Unable to Create Active Volume in OpenStack

Tags: openstack, openstack-horizon

Every volume I create generates an error -- I deployed using MicroStack

[snippit of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnCRB.png)

text error below

> schedule allocate volume:Could not find any available weighted backend

I have Cinder Services as seen here

[snippit of services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3YEj.png)

How can I troubleshoot this?
I have created a Physical Volume of 500GB on my Server

```
 PV         VG             Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree
  /dev/sdc5  cinder-volumes lvm2 a--  <500.00g <500.00g
```

How can I get OpenStack to utilize that new Volume as the "Storage Back End" ?

I assume that is what I missing, but I am having trouble finding any relation

Most documentation online I have found references "DevStack" installs and not what I used:  MicroStack from https://microstack.run/docs/multi-node

Comment: On my Microstack, the Cinder configuration file is at /var/snap/microstack/common/etc/cinder/cinder.conf.d/cinder-snap.conf. It has a single backend that uses LVM volume group *cinder-volumes*. Perhaps the volume group is not working on your installation? Microstack uses a loop-device-based physical volume; you could replace it with a larger loop device, or simply add another backend based on another loop device. Instructions to add a backend are at https://docs.openstack.org/cinder/latest/admin/blockstorage-multi-backend.html.

Comment: Strangely, https://microstack.run/docs says "Supported services are currently Glance, Horizon, Keystone, Neutron, and Nova". Nothing about Cinder.

Comment: yeahh, I saw that on a Juju/Charm Forum from Ubuntu -- derppp